# I am getting the leak in the following code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am getting the leaks as 100%. I don't know how to release the object after it returns
Could you explain the procedure how to release the allocated Titles object.

```
-(Titles *)listTiles
{
Tiles* tile = [[Tiles alloc] init];
 tile.googleTile_X = (int)tileX;
 tile.googleTile_Y = (int) pow(2, aZoom) - 1- tileY ;
 tile.zoomLevel = aZoom; 
 return tile;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it depends, but in that particular case I believe you can use `return [tile autorelease]`.

P.S.: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending `-alloc,` and failing to send `-release` or `-autorelease` to the object you've created.

Read Apple's introductory documentation on memory management.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(Titles *)listTiles
{
    Tiles* tile = [[[Tiles alloc] init] autorelease];
    tile.googleTile_X = (int)tileX;
    tile.googleTile_Y = (int) pow(2, aZoom) - 1- tileY ;
    tile.zoomLevel = aZoom; 
    return tile;
}
```